# IF Formula help - Multiple Parameters Issue

Tags: formula, formula-field, if

Im new to salesforce formulas and need to implement this new field (New_License_Manager_ID__c) into the formula.

I received an Error:

> Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3,
> received 4

Here's the formula:    `IF(NOT(OR(ISNULL(Current_Customer_ID__c),ISBLANK(Current_Customer_ID__c))),Current_Customer_ID__c,BT_Account_Number__c, New_License_Manager_ID__c)`

Comment: Can you add more detail to the question like what do you need to add the field to the forumula . Do you need to check any condition for the new field?

Comment: Order should be Current ID, then BT, then New License. The Old formula : IF(NOT(OR(ISNULL(Current_Customer_ID__c),ISBLANK(current_Customer_ID__c))),current_Customer_ID__c,BT_Account_Number__c).

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please visit [help] and [ask] to understand about general guidelines on how to post questions in this forum. Additionally, please refer to SF developer guides and try to elaborate on what you have tried, in order to get quicker responses. As the error message suggests, you are passing 4 parameters to `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)` which accepts only 3 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> IF(ISBLANK(Current_Customer_ID__c),IF(ISBLANK(BT_Account_Number__c),
> New_License_Manager_ID__c, BT_Account_Number__c),
> Current_Customer_ID__c)

or

> IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Current_Customer_ID__c)), Current_Customer_ID__c,
> IF(NOT(ISBLANK(BT_Account_Number__c)), BT_Account_Number__c,
> New_License_Manager_ID__c))

Since [IF](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_if.htm&type=5) support only 3 parameters (condition, value on true & value on false), you will have to use nested IF conditions in the formula.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!